# AWS S3 bucket policy with condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to S3 bucket polices. In S3 documentation, I found one Bucket policy(attached below). I am not sure what does mean. Does it mean, No-one can do any action(put, read, delete,...) except this user:"AROAEXAMPLEID:*","AIDAEXAMPLEID","111111111111"? Can anyone please verify?

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "AIDAEXAMPLEID",
            "111111111111"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break the policy part by part to help you better understand:

```
 "Principal": "*", - all users 
 "Action": "s3:*" - all actions related to s3
 "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
  ] - for my example buckets and its objects
```

Now let's understand condition:

```
"Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "AIDAEXAMPLEID",
            "111111111111"
          ]
        }
```

If string **does not contain** the mentioned userid which means this condition is **true**, if this condition is true since **effect= Deny** is true which means users which do no have the mentioned user id won't be able to perform S3 actions on these buckets.

If this condition is not true which means **if it contains** userid which are mentioned which means they will be able to perform all S3 operations on the mentioned bucket.